# Server Control Error: Unknown server tag with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to get a custom control working in **VB ASP.Net**

I've read a few threads but it doesn't seem to help me much.
I have a solution including:

- **Website** project called "SiteCI"
- **Class Library** project called "SiteCI-classes"

The website project has a reference to the library project, and the library DLL are correctly generated inside the bin folder of the website project.

When I create a random class within the website project, I can access to my test control class  called MailLink by typing:

```
SiteCI_classes.Controls.MailLink
```

It works perfectly, Visual Studio suggests it to me, so the **link between the two projects are correctly set**.

Please note that I **clean/rebuild** the project every time to see if it really works or not, so that's not a problem of incorrect DLL build.

In the Web Config file inside system.web -> pages -> controls I have added:

```
<add assembly="SiteCI-classes" namespace="Controls" tagPrefix="custom" />
```

But on a ASP.Net page when I add:

```
<custom:MailLink runat="server" id="test1"></custom:MailLink>
```

I am getting the ***Unknown server tag 'custom:MailLink'*** error.

To check if I did not make a mistake while typing in the web config file I tried to change the SiteCI-classes to SiteCI_classes and I got an error saying that it wasn't able to load the assembly, so I guess that part is OK, and then I tried to change ***namespace="Controls"*** in ***namespace="SiteCI_classes.Controls"*** or ***namespace="SiteCI-classes.Controls"*** and it didn't fix the unknown server tag issue.

I don't know what to do... it's supposed to work, isn't it?

Here is the MailLink.vb that is located in a folder called ***Controls*** of the Library project. It's a class I picked on a Microsoft page just for testing purpose.

I would be very grateful if anyone could give me a tip on what to check.

```
Namespace Controls
    < _
    AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, _
        Level:=AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal), _
    AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand, _
        Level:=AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal), _
    DefaultProperty("Email"), _
    ParseChildren(True, "Text"), _
    ToolboxData("<{0}:MailLink runat=""server""> </{0}:MailLink>") _
    > _
    Public Class MailLink
        Inherits WebControl

        < _
        Bindable(True), _
        Category("Appearance"), _
        DefaultValue(""), _
        Description("The e-mail address.") _
        > _
        Public Overridable Property Email() As String
            Get
                Dim s As String = CStr(ViewState("Email"))
                If s Is Nothing Then s = String.Empty
                Return s
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                ViewState("Email") = value
            End Set
        End Property

        < _
        Bindable(True), _
        Category("Appearance"), _
        DefaultValue(""), _
        Description("The text to display on the link."), _
        Localizable(True), _
        PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty) _
        > _
        Public Overridable Property Text() As String
            Get
                Dim s As String = CStr(ViewState("Text"))
                If s Is Nothing Then s = String.Empty
                Return s
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                ViewState("Text") = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property TagKey() _
            As HtmlTextWriterTag
            Get
                Return HtmlTextWriterTag.A
            End Get
        End Property


        Protected Overrides Sub AddAttributesToRender( _
            ByVal writer As HtmlTextWriter)
            MyBase.AddAttributesToRender(writer)
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, _
                "mailto:" & Email)
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub RenderContents( _
            ByVal writer As HtmlTextWriter)
            If (Text = String.Empty) Then
                Text = Email
            End If
            writer.WriteEncodedText(Text)
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem which seem to have **ONLY been caused by the dash** ("-") in the name of the Project.

The name of the project is still "SiteCI-Classes" **BUT** the final code of the WebConfig is different:

```
<add assembly="SiteCIClasses" namespace="SiteCI2KClasses.Controls" tagPrefix="cc1" />
```

Note the difference between the two. ASP.Net 3.5 will not recognize a dash in the name of a project and seem to remove it: if you try to set it to SiteCI-Classes it will end up with an error like **assembly not found**.